# Google Analytics API v.4 returning wrong users value on Android and iOS apps

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Using Google Analytics' API I'm getting a report (sessions, users, new/returning users, page views, bounce rate, etc...) on all devices, every value is correct except "users" value on my Android and iOS devices. Google Analytic's returning over 2.5x amount of value that is shown in Google Analytic website, I've also used [this link](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer) and it's returning the same value as Google Analytics website.

This is only happening to apps analytics, on a desktop and mobile site everything's fine.

I've already checked the sampling level, not sure what else could go wrong.

I'd appreciate the help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Google's API v.4 sent the sum of users of each day in a date range instead of unique value, using `ga:7dayUsers` or `ga:30dayUsers` as metric fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with Google Analytics's API v.4 that returned the aggregation of users within the provided date range instead of unique users.

I don't know if the problem still exists, but I managed to use `ga:7dayUsers` or `ga:30dayUsers` type of metrics to retrieve my unique users.